# How can I detect a sequence of "hollows" (holes, lines not matching a pattern) bigger than n in a text file?

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing

Case **scenario**:

```
$ cat Status.txt
1,connected
2,connected
3,connected
4,connected
5,connected
6,connected
7,disconnected
8,disconnected
9,disconnected
10,disconnected
11,disconnected
12,disconnected
13,disconnected
14,connected
15,connected
16,connected
17,disconnected
18,connected
19,connected
20,connected
21,disconnected
22,disconnected
23,disconnected
24,disconnected
25,disconnected
26,disconnected
27,disconnected
28,disconnected
29,disconnected
30,connected
```

As can be seen, there are "hollows", understanding them as **lines with the "disconnected"** value inside the sequence file.

I want, in fact, to **detect** these "holes", but it would be useful if I could set a **minimum `n` of missing numbers** in the sequence.
I.e: for ' n=5'  a detectable hole would be the `7... 13` part, as there are at least 5 "disconnected" in a row on the sequence. However, the missing `17` should not be considered as detectable in this case. Again, at line 21 whe get a valid disconnection.

Something like:

```
$ detector Status.txt -n 5 --pattern connected
7
21
```

... that could be interpreted like:

```
- Missing more than 5 "connected" starting at 7.
- Missing more than 5 "connected" starting at 21.
```

I need to script this on **Linux shell**, so I was thinking about programing some loop, parsing strings and so on, but I feel like if this could be done by using **linux shell tools** and maybe some simpler programming. Is there a way?

Even when small programs like `csvtool` are a valid solution, some more common Linux commands (like `grep`, `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, `wc`... etc) could be worth for me when working with embedded devices.

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yourself? Is there a operation you need to know how to do before you start? (All I can see this needing is (1) ability to iterate line-by-line; (2) ability to split out columns; (3) ability to compare a column's value against a fixed string; (4) ability to store a number in a variable; (5) ability to do a numeric comparison -- those are all fairly simple primitives).

Comment: Reading content line-by-line, f/e, is the subject of [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: My attempts were based on `grep -A 5`, and multiple chained `grep` commands, but they gave no results, so I thought it had no sense to publish them and risking to enlarge the original question.

Comment: BTW, it's more efficient to run `foo <file.txt` rather than `cat file.txt | foo` -- sometimes *substantially* more efficient, if `foo` is a program like `sort` that can optimize by splitting off threads or subprocesses to handle a subset of the input (which depends on those threads being able to skip directly to the part of the input they're individually handling, which you can't do with a pipe). Likewise `wc -c <in.txt` is **far** more efficient than `cat in.txt | wc -c`, since with a handle on the real file, `wc` can just `seek()` straight to the end without reading everything between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
last_connected=0
min_hole_size=${1:-5}  # default to 5, or take an argument from the command line
while IFS=, read -r num state; do
  if [[ $state = connected ]]; then
    if (( (num-last_connected) > (min_hole_size+1) )); then
      echo "Found a hole running from $((last_connected + 1)) to $((num - 1))"
    fi
    last_connected=$num
  fi
done

# Special case: Need to also handle a hole that's still open at EOF.
if [[ $state != connected ]] && (( num - last_connected > min_hole_size )); then
  echo "Found a hole running from $((last_connected + 1)) to $num"
fi
```

...emits, given your file on stdin (`./detect-holes <in.txt`):

```
Found a hole running from 7 to 13
Found a hole running from 21 to 29
```

---

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*
- [The conditional expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) -- the `[[ ]]` syntax used to make it safe to do string comparisons without quoting expansions.
- [Arithmetic comparison syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr#comparisons) -- valid in `$(( ))` in all POSIX-compliant shells; also available without the expansion side effects as `(( ))` as a bash extension.

Comment: Since your last modification, I get `line 6: ((: {1:-5}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1:-5}")` .

Comment: Oops -- somehow dropped a character. Should have been `${1:-5}`.

Comment: The case "hole that's still open at EOF" seems not to be working. I have changed `30,connected` to `30,disconnected` on my original `Status.txt` file and the last hole is not detected.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that. See this code run with the interactive interpreter at https://ideone.com/gGzLLn -- it correctly includes in its output `Found a hole running from 21 to 30`.

Comment: MMmm... see my results: https://ideone.com/0id54b . What am I doing wrong? The code is copy-pasted from your answer.

Comment: Looks like you've got a blank line at the end of the input file, so that last `read -r num state` overwrites what would otherwise be the final values.

Comment: You are right on the stdin matter. But issuing `sed '/^$/d' < Status.txt > Status-.txt` both .txt files have the same size. Same with `cat Status.txt | grep -v "^$" > Status-.txt`, so the input file should have no blank lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164136/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-sopalajo-de-arrierez).

Comment: I have declared this one the accepted answer, but only because I have deeply tested it (it works!), and the loop is more readable (easier to understand) than the other AWK methods. I could change my decision if, in a future, I implement the others, and speed tests show a better efficiency.

Comment: awk certainly *is* faster than bash -- among other reasons, bash's `read` primitive consumes one character at a time, whereas awk's is able to operate in bigger chunks; if you're dealing with a large enough input file, that alone will be significant.

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect use case for awk, since the machinery of line reading, column splitting, and matching is all built in. The only tricky bit is getting the command line argument to your script, but it's not too bad:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
awk -v window="$1" -F, '
BEGIN { if (window=="") {window = 1} }

$2=="disconnected"{if (consecutive==0){start=NR}; consecutive++}
$2!="disconnected"{if (consecutive>window){print start}; consecutive=0}

END {if (consecutive>window){print start}}'
```

The `window` value is supplied as the first command line argument; left out, it defaults to 1, which means "display the start of gaps with at least two consecutive disconnections". Probably could have a better name. You can give it 0 to include single disconnections. Sample output below. (Note that I added series of 2 disconnections at the end to test the failure that Charles metions).

```
njv@organon:~/tmp$ ./tst.sh 0 < status.txt # any number of disconnections
7
17
21
31
njv@organon:~/tmp$ ./tst.sh < status.txt # at least 2 disconnections
7
21
31
njv@organon:~/tmp$ ./tst.sh 8 < status.txt # at least 9 disconnections
21
```

Comment: I agree that awk is a good tool for this case, but if I wanted to be a bit contrarian, I'd point out that everything used for the same purposes in my native-bash implementation is *also* pure builtins, with no external commands involved.

Comment: Please, Nathan, where is the `5` value on this AWK code, in order to change it later for, say, `7` or `8`?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, the `5` is taken off the argument list -- coming from the `"$1"`.

Comment: @Nathan, BTW, I think you've got the same bug I presently do (ed: now, *initially did*), wrt. failing to report on a hole that's still ongoing at EOF. Should probably have an `END` block handling that case.

Comment: Oh. I was testing by piping. Just `cat Status.txt | ./prueba3.sh` (with no `5` as parameter) yields the correct `7` and `21` numbers. Same results for `cat Status.txt | ./prueba3.sh 2` and `cat Status.txt | ./prueba3.sh 1`. The simplest `./prueba3.sh 5 Status.txt`  freezes without showing any results. Maybe you could supply syntax usage?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - yes indeed! Thanks for pointing that out. Edited my answer. FWIW I wasn't referring to your answer when I said everything is built in with awk - I hadn't even seen it yet :)

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - as written it only works with piping, yes. You can use almost the same syntax, though: `./prueba3.sh 5 < Status.txt`. I'll add usage to my answer, good idea.

Comment: Since your last modification the program is not working. Results for `./tst.sh 0 < status.txt` are `7`, `17` and `21` 3 times, And multiple leading blank lines.

Comment: Sorry, trying edit from the phone was probably not very wise!  I'll fix it in a few hours when I am home again.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - fixed! I was missing an "=" in the BEGIN section.

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

**`detector.awk`** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }
$2 == "disconnected"{ 
    if (f && NR-c==nr) c++; 
    else { f=1; c++; nr=NR } 
}
$2 == "connected"{ 
    if (f) { 
        if (c > n) { 
            printf "- Missing more than 5 \042connected\042 starting at %d.\n", nr 
        } 
        f=c=0 
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f detector.awk -v n=5 status.txt
```

The output:

```
- Missing more than 5 "connected" starting at 7.
- Missing more than 5 "connected" starting at 21.
```

Comment: A minor chosmetic bug, Roman, on `more than 5` when the `n` value is not `5`.

Comment: I'm always happy to see some awk written for readability rather than terseness.